# How do I get a list of all Trello Labels for a board?

Tags: javascript, trello

When I pull down the board, I do get a labelNames field, but only one label per color. I have multiple labels sharing a color and I want to list all of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's special call to list all labels defined in specific board by ID, you need to use:

`\boards\[boardID]\labels`

It'll return json formatted like:

```
{
    "id": "label_id",
    "idBoard": "board_id",
    "name": "label_name",
    "color": "green",
    "uses": number_of_cards_that_uses_this_label
}
```

Comment: Does this still work in 2024 ?
I just tried 
curl --request GET --url 'https://api.trello.com/boards/<BOARD-ID>/labels?key=<KEY>&token=<TOKEN>'
and got an empty response.

Comment: Finally figured it out : I had to add a 1/ in front of the url for this to work:
curl -X GET 'https://api.trello.com/1/boards/<BOARD-ID>/labels?key=<KEY>&token=<TOKEN>'